# Styled checkboxes inside an overlay - checked always = false

Tags: html, checkbox

I am using a jQuery plugin for styling HTML checkboxes/radio buttons. The problem is that when these checkboxes appear inside of a lightbox overlay, their checked property can never be set to "true." They visually appear checked of course but they aren't really and this doesn't work in a .NET environment.

I have tried other plugins and I've tried digging into the code for this particular plugin (prettycheckboxes). It seems there is some issue with the input element being positioned absolutely and off the page (left: -9999px) because when i remove this from the CSS and instead use visibility: hidden, the checkboxes work again.

However, in addition to the checkboxes that appear inside of my lightbox, I also have an accordion type element inside of the lightbox that also contains checkboxes. These do NOT work no matter what i do to the CSS.

When the prettycheckboxes plugin is either removed, the checkboxes of course work. If i place the prettycheckboxes styled elements outside of the lightbox, they work.

Anyone else experience this issue?

Comment: Have you tried setting the checkboxes to false through a jquery function in your HTML document?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I've fixed the problem though I'm not really sure why this worked. Apparently with this plugin (prettyCheckboxes), there is some issue with how the inputs are originally rendered, their visibility or position. The CSS for the inputs (as the original prettycheckboxes css was written) goes:

```
input.hiddenCheckbox{position:absolute;left:-10000px;}
```

.hiddenCheckbox is the class that gets applied to checkboxes by the prettyCheckboxes plugin. This worked fine for checkboxes that were NOT inside of a lightbox. But when inside lightbox their checked property wouldn't check. I changed it to this:

```
input.hiddenCheckbox{visibility: hidden;}
```

this fixed the issue in FF and Chrome but not in IE7/8

For IE7/8 i had to do this:

```
input.hiddenCheckbox{height: 0;visibility: visible;}
```

Again, I am not sure why this works but it does. I'm not completely satisfied with this though. Anyone have any idea why this would work?